# in JNI, how to assign values to jobjectArray?

Tags: java-native-interface

I have an array of objects which is initialized in Java as shown below:

```cpp
Record[] pRecords = new Record[5];
ret = GetRecord(pRecords);
```

I passed this array to the JNI, from JNI it will call CPP, and finally the array will get filled.

```cpp
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_GetRecord
  (JNIEnv *jEnv, jobject ObjApp, jobjectArray jRecords)
{
    Record  *pRecords = (Record *)malloc(5*sizeof(Record  ));   

    ret = Get_Record(pRecords); // call to CPP
    if(SUCCESS == ret)
    {
        jclass c = (jEnv)->GetObjectClass(jRecords);
        jfieldID  fid = (jEnv)->GetFieldID(c, "m_session", "I");
        (jEnv)->SetIntField (jRecords, fid, pRecords [0].value);
    }
}
```

I am getting `fid` `NULL`. How to assign `pRecords[0].value` to 0th array of `jRecords` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `jobjectArray` is *not* a pointer to the first element of the array. Remember that Java arrays are themselves first-class objects.

`fid` is 0 because you're looking for a member `m_session` in the class that represents an array of the Java class `Record`; of course the array class has no such member. You need to do a `FindClass()` to get the `Record` class, and then look for the member in there.

Then you proceed to try to set that member. If it's actually a member of the `Record` class, I'd imagine you want to set the value of that member in each array element in a loop, yes? Certainly not in the array itself, as you're trying to do. For each array element you need to call the appropriate method to get the object in that array position, then operate on that object.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. Now I am getting fid. How to assign value to 0th object of jRecord? (jEnv)->SetIntField (jRecords, fid, pRecords [0].value); In Java I want, pRecords[0].m_session = pRecords [0].value of JNI

Comment: Based on your Java code above, jRecords is a five-element array of `null` elements -- i.e., you need to create the `Record` objects. It would be a little simpler to just do that in Java before passing the array in. Then loop over the array in your JNI code, calling `getObjectArrayElement(env, jRecords, i)` five times to get the `Record` objects, setting the member in each one. Your member-setting code is basically OK, it's just being applied to the wrong object.

Comment: jobject pe = (jEnv)->GetObjectArrayElement(jRecords, 0); getting NULL. In Java I have created elements in Record

Comment: Well, you may *think* you have, but it looks like you haven't. Can I see the modified Java code that creates the array and then calls the native method?

Comment: public class Record
{
 public int m_session;  
 public int m_size   
};
Record[]pRecords = new Record[5];
ret = GetRecord(pRecords);

Comment: I am getting GetArrayLength(jRecord); as 5. But GetObjectArrayElement return NULL.

Comment: In Java, you have to actually create all five `Record` objects individually. An array of objects is an array of *references* to separate objects; it's like an array of pointers-to-object in C++. So: `Record[] pRecords = new Record[5]; for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) pRecords[i] = new Record(); ret = GetRecord(pRecords);`